# A static object while its destructor is scope aware

Tags: c++

This is a simple form of my problem. I have a static object `A` in function `f` and we know the destructor of that object will be invoked after finishing the program not exiting of `f`.

But this object needs to know when its scope is going to exit and then it will execute its destuctor. To make it automatic, I've written a helper class `AutoScope` which is in a scope as same as that object.

```
struct A {
    A() {
        cout << "Hi" << endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout << "Bye" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct AutoScope {
    T &t;
public:
    AutoScope(T &t) : t(t) {
    }
    ~AutoScope() {
        t.~T();
    }
};

void f() {
    static A a;
    AutoScope<A> tmp(a);
}

int main() {
    f();
    f();
    f();

    cout << "end!" << endl;
}
```

Output

```
Hi
Bye
Bye
Bye
end!
Bye
```

OK, I'm wondering that is there any way to combine this to class to have that functionality. A class which is static and simultaneously its destructor is invoking as same as non-static objects.

Comment: Why do you want it to be `static` if you want to destroy it at the end of its scope?

Comment: @Malloc: The internal of that object should be remain after each execution of `f`. I don't want make it global.

Comment: @MeysamHit, Are you merely trying to preserve the memory, but call the destructor as if it were any other function?

Comment: @merlin2011: Somehow, but there is not dangerous objects in the class.

Comment: Destructing an object turns it into raw memory. What "internals" do you want to retain and why?

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Some `int`s (no pointers, no allocated memory, ...)

Comment: Ok, we have the what. What about the why? Also, if you want the internals to persist, why do you want to destroy the object between calls?

Comment: @MarceloCantos: Making some repeating codes automated. I need to do something when the scope finishes while the internals are remaining.

Comment: Why does that something require you to destroy a static object?

Comment: I'm not persisting on calling the destructor, we can replace it by another method.

Comment: @MarceloCantos, I think he's just trying to add an end-function hoook, which is why I think he needs to have a function-scope object. I do not know of any way to achieve what he's trying to do *without* a function-scope object, but if you do, please add an answer, since I would be curious to know if this is possible.

Comment: If the static object is used, then on second call of f you have **Undefined Behavior**, using an already destroyed object. If it isn't used, then it's -- useless? Could you please clarify the intended usage here, because any way I look at it it seems meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are trying to achieve is similar to the behavior of `std::lock_guard` with `std::mutex`.

You want to call a particular function (in this case the destructor) on an object when a particular scope ends.

I do not believe this is possible without the additional class, because the scope of a static object is global and there's no mechanism in `c++` as far as I know to tell detect the end of a smaller scope without the use of a helper object which is scoped to that local scope.

I would recommend changing `~A()` to some other function though, because the function's purpose is not really associated with "destruction" per se, since you are not actually destroying the object.

Comment: Yes, I can replace `~A()` by another method but I was looking for a way to combine that two classes. Maybe meta-programming is useful!

Comment: @MeysamHit, I think what you have already done is one of the standard ways to to this (add a function-end hook). That is why I mentioned the `std::lock_guard` and `std::mutex`, since the standard library does it this way.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is guarantee some code gets called on exit from the function, the best thing is to bind it up in a local-object destructor as you've done. There's no need for that object to destroy the static object, though. Instead of calling `t.~T()`, just call some cleanup member function, e.g., `t.cleanup()`.

If you're using C++11 (most compilers support it by now) you could construct a more generic class for this using lambdas:

```
struct AutoScope {
    std::function<void()> f;
    AutoScope(std::function<void()> const &f) : f(f) { }
    ~AutoScope() { f(); }
};

void f() {
    static A a;
    AutoScope tmp([&]{
        // Do cleanup here.
    });
}
```

Comment: For C++03 compilers use [Petru Marginean's original ScopeGuard](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/generic-change-the-way-you-write-excepti/184403758). Also, just in passing, although I prefer to implement a C++11 scope guard class as shown in this answer, one person has argued strongly that it's abuse of `std::function`, and that instead one should make the function a template parameter, and support the class with a factory function with argument deduction. That also requires some extra machinery for releasing the scope guard, if that functionality is desirable (and it sometimes is).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I thought of using a template class, but I couldn't immediately see how to instantiate it, since you can't name the lambda's type. I could use inner-class delegation, but that seems like `std::function<…>` by any other name.